# not working for some reason not definied?

Tags: python

```
import random

def question():

    OperatorChoice = random.randrange(1,2)

    if OperatorChoice == 1:
        Choice = ("+")
    else:
        Choice = ("-")
Random1 = random.randrange(1,50)
Random2 = random.randrange(1,50)
print (Random1, Choice, Random2)

question()
```

for some reason it doesn't work please help

```
 <module>
    print (Random1, Choice, Random2)
NameError: name 'Choice' is not defined
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect - those lines (`Random1 = ... ` to `print (...)`) are *outside* the `question` function

Comment: You should try to pick a title that actually gives some information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
print (Random1, Choice, Random2)
```

is causing the problem because `Choice` is undefined in the global scope (where you're trying to access it). It doesn't matter that the *function* `question()` was *defined* before that.

In fact, that situation wouldn't even change if you had *called* `question()` before calling `print()` because `Choice` is a local variable to `question` and is therefore invisible outside of it.

A better way to do this would be to define the following function:

```
def question():
    return "+" if random.randint(0,1) else "-"
```

but you don't need to do that anyway:

Just use

```
random1 = random.randrange(1,50)
random2 = random.randrange(1,50)
choice = random.choice("+-")
print (random1, choice, random2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `question()` before the `print()`. Otherwise, `Choice` is defined after it is referenced.

In addition to this, the `question()` function should have `global Choice` on its first line, so that `Choice` is a global variable.

Comment: While technically correct, that would be a terrible habit to get into. Setting global variables from inside a function is something that should be done only if absolutely necessary. Much better do have `question()` `return Choice` and assign that to the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of`OperatorChoice = random.randrange(1,2)` and then making an operation off of which number it gives you, you can simply use `OperatorChoice = random.choice(['+', '-'])`.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with `def question():`

But your problem is that you defined `Choice` in the function question. Getting rid of that, your code would be:

```
import random


OperatorChoice = random.choice(['+','-'])

Random1 = random.randrange(1,50)
Random2 = random.randrange(1,50)

print (Random1, OperatorChoice, Random2)
```

I'm not sure if that's what your looking for, if it isn't, let me know.